# Issue using FileDialog Application

Tags: vba, excel

I have a bit of code which I am trying to improve but having some issues.

The code is currently:

```
    Sub TestListFilesInFolder()
'Workbooks.Add ' create a new workbook for the file list
' add headers

Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) ' Tried using a FileDialog Application  but had no luck

With Range("A1")
    .Formula = "Folder contents:"
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Size = 12
End With
Range("A3").Formula = "Old File Path:"
Range("B3").Formula = "File Type:"
Range("C3").Formula = "File Name:"
Range("D3").Formula = "New File Path:"
Range("A3:H3").Font.Bold = True
ListFilesInFolder "L:\Pictures\A B C\B526 GROUP", True
' ListFilesInFolder fd, True ' I tried replacing the above line with this line but get an error

' list all files included subfolders
 End Sub
```

Line 5 and 6 is a part I have added in where I am trying to get a file dialog to open where the user can choose the folder for the code to work on.

Also The commented out line near the bottom starting ListFilesInFolder is the one I tried inserting to replace the line above it.

The start of the next bit of code is:

```
   Sub ListFilesInFolder(SourceFolderName As String, IncludeSubfolders As Boolean)
```

So it uses the folder and subfolders of that folder defined in the first sub.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Regards,

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `fd` as the first parameter to your `ListFilesInFolder` sub. This sub accepts a `String` as the first parameter, **not** a `FileDialog`.

Here's some sample code that, when executed, will open a file dialog and let the user select a folder. Once selected, it will print the path of the folder to `B2`. If no folder is selected (e.g. dialog is closed or canceled), `B2` will contain the text `No item selected`.

I think you should create a new workbook and play around with this macro. Set a break point and walk through it, see what it's actually doing. Then you can alter it to make it work for your specific needs.

```
Public Sub SelectExportDestinationPath()
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then
            sItem = "No item selected"
        Else
            sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

    'if trailing slash is not found, add it
    If Len(sItem) > 0 And InStr(Len(sItem), sItem, Application.PathSeparator, vbCompareText) = 0 Then
        sItem = sItem & Application.PathSeparator
    End If

    Sheet1.Cells(2, 2).Value = sItem

    Set fldr = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: No problem - glad to help. Best of luck with the rest of your project.

Answer (score -1):

make sure you have the appropriate reference picked:

> Press Alt+F11 to open the VB Editor. In that window, choose menu items Tools -> References..., then look down the list for **Microsoft Office XXX Object Library**
>   *It's 11.0 for Access 2003, 10.0 for Access 2002; 9.0 for Access 2000, 8.0 for Access 97 -- pick the right one.*
>   Put a check mark in the box next to that reference, then close the dialog.

or, use the actual values, not the mso values

```
msoFileDialogOpen=1
msoFileDialogSaveAs=2
msoFileDialogFilePicker=3
msoFileDialogFolderPicker=4
```